# iterate over array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do some validation on a user selecting items from a list. I want to make sure an item is not added twice by checking if the `<li>` is already in the array. This is what I'm trying and its not working.

```
 $(".List").on("click", "li", function () {
 var i = 0;
 var checkArr = [];

 var div = $("#AddedItems");
 var parent = $(this).closest("ul");
 var itemtoadd = parent.find("[data-id]").attr("data-id");
 var name = parent.find("[data-name]").attr("data-name");

 alert(itemtoadd + name);//checking 

 var itemtoadd = ("<li id = " + itemtoadd + " class = \"itemAdd\">" + name + "</li>");

 checkArr.push(itemtoadd); //put one in to check against?
 checkArr.forEach(item)
 {
     if (item == itemtoadd)
         alert("this item has already been added");
     else {
         checkArr.push(itemtoadd);
         alert(itemtoadd);
         $(itemtoadd).appendTo(div);
     }
 }
 // div.html(itemtoadd);


 });
```

Comment: You can also just use a regular for loop, that's probably faster.

Comment: I don't know if this is important to your use case but Array.forEach isn't supported in IE 8 and below. [Mozilla Developer link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach)

Comment: I read that. I may move to a `.each()`

Comment: Even if you get your `for` right, you're still going to have two problems, as described in my answer. Handily, you don't actually *need* a loop here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three problems here:

1. You aren't using `Array.forEach` correctly -- it takes a function that takes an item.
2. Immediately before you do your check, you're adding the item you're looking for. You will always hit the `alert` case.
3. You're using `checkArr` as a local variable -- you're getting an empty array each time you enter the function.

That all being said, you can accomplish your goal without keeping an array at all. I believe you can replace everything from your first alert down with this:

```
if ($('#' + itemtoadd, div).length == 0) {
    itemtoadd = ("<li id = " + itemtoadd + " class = \"itemAdd\">" + name + "</li>");
    div.append(itemtoadd);
}
else {
    alert("this item has already been added");
}
```

Comment: ok. let me sort this out. My first alert is this? `alert(itemtoadd + name);//checking ` and where does the error message go, in the `else`?

Comment: Also, the user can add up to 4 items so I'm not just checking one item. Every time an item is added I need to check if its already in the div.

Comment: Yes, sorry -- I've updated the answer to reflect adding the error message. ... And yes -- I understand that's what you're trying to do. I was just saying that your code as written doesn't do that. Every time an item is added you're creating a *new instance* of `checkArr`.